# Entity Framework duplicate key issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity called `Users`, and an en entity called `Groups`.

I have a few groups confined in my database already, but no users.  I am trying to add users, and configure groups for them, but I receive the following error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Groups'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.Groups'. The duplicate key value is
>   (admins). The statement has been terminated.

Entities are defined as follows (some info stripped)

```
public class User{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("Organization")]
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Organization {get;set;}
    public virtual Organization Org {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups {get;set;}
}

public class Group {
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public string GroupName {get;set;}
}
```

Am i missing something basic here?

Code I am using to add users:

```
var user = new User 
{
    Name = "NAME", 
    Organization = "Organization Name", 
    Org = orgObject, 
    Groups = LIST OF GROUPS    // LIST OF GROUPS is an IList<Group> object
};
context.Users.Add(user);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Show the code you're using for adding users.

Comment: Hm, thought I did, guess it didn't save. Editing now :)

Comment: @appsecguy, you did have the code. When voytek edited your post he removed that part of the question. Not sure why that edit was approved.

Comment: My thought is that because the List<Group> was obtained elsewhere, rather than from the db context, it is trying to re-add it when it already exists.  Would that be accurate?

Comment: @appsecguy: You're correct as to the reason why it's happening. I'm trying to figure out how to fix the problem. I think part of the problem is a fundamental issue with the model. It seems like you have a many-to-many (a group can have many users and a user can belong to many groups) but the model doesn't really reflect that. And using the group name as the primary key for groups isn't a great idea either.

Comment: @CraigW. That's weird, I didn't remove it. Btw. my edit was approved by the author anyway

Comment: @Craig - What is the best way to reflect that relationship in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My thought is that because the List was obtained elsewhere, rather than from the db context, it is trying to re-add it when it already exists. Would that be accurate?

Correct. You have to attach the items to current dbContext to make it work.

```
var user = new User 
{
    Name = "NAME", 
    Organization = "Organization Name", 
    Org = orgObject, 
    Groups = LIST OF GROUPS    // LIST OF GROUPS is an IList<Group> object
};

foreach(var group in LIST OF GROUPS)
    context.Groups.Attach(group);

context.Users.Add(user);
context.SaveChanges();
```